# Disable accelerometer for a period of time then enable it

Tags: objective-c

I have an app where u can move a man with the accelerometer. There is a ready set go sequence and then using pop Animation the guy appears. Although even when the man is not visible and the ready set go words appear the accelerometer is still usable and u can move the guy and accidentally touch the obstacle which then using cgrectintersectsrect changes to An end game screen. So in that ready set go sequence how can I disable the accelerometer then reenable it when the go word appears?

.h:

```
@interface GameScreen : UIViewController <UIAccelerometerDelegate>  {

IBOutlet UIImageView *image1;
IBOutlet UIImageView *image2;
UIImageView *ball;
CGPoint delta;
IBOutlet UIImageView *man;
IBOutlet UIImageView *fang;
IBOutlet UIImageView* hiddenView;
IBOutlet UILabel* ready;
IBOutlet UILabel* set;
IBOutlet UILabel* go;   
IBOutlet UILabel* endScreen;
IBOutlet UIImageView* guy;


CAKeyframeAnimation *popAnimation;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain)UIImageView *image1;
@property (nonatomic, retain)UIImageView *image2;

-(void)checkCollision;

@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UIImageView *ball;
@property CGPoint delta;
@end
```

.m:

```
-(void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {

NSLog(@"x : %g", acceleration.x);
NSLog(@"y : %g", acceleration.y);
NSLog(@"z : %g", acceleration.z);

delta.y = acceleration.y * 50;
delta.x = acceleration.x * 50;

ball.center = CGPointMake(ball.center.x + delta.x, ball.center.y + delta.y);

// Right
if(ball.center.x < 0) {
    ball.center = CGPointMake(320, ball.center.y);
}

// Left

if(ball.center.x > 320) {
    ball.center = CGPointMake(0, ball.center.y);

}

// Top

if(ball.center.y < 0) {
    ball.center = CGPointMake(ball.center.x, 460);

}

// Bottom
if(ball.center.y > 460){
    ball.center = CGPointMake(ball.center.x, 0);

}
[self checkCollision];

}
```

Comment: One way (may not be the best way) of doing that is to set the *delegate* property to *nil* at times when you don't want the man to move.

Comment: Not what I'm looking for

Comment: If not you can have a flag value to check if the man's movement is allowed or not.

Comment: I am very new to c and I do not know what u are talking about please supply code and also I can't give u my code because right now I'm in school it's lunch time and there's Internet and please dot get angry at me i am only 12 and new to this

Comment: @user735415, you don't know what a flag is? It doesn't matter how old you are, I think you need to read a book on programming before asking specific question on SO. Because no one here on SO is going to hold your hands.

Comment: Some code would be helpful. I am also limited in time because I'm on the bus to go to an excursion and its leaving soon

Comment: @Simon, write your comment in the answer below, and I will give it an up vote.

Comment: I can't afford a book right now my dad recently enrolled me in the developer program and I don't think he wants to spend much more money

Comment: flag(c) returns all the values of the flag c each time it is present in the command line, an empty list otherwise. 
flag?(c) returns true if the flag c is present in the command line, false otherwise. 
In both functions, the optional argument s contains a list of flag codes which cause the rest of the argument to be skipped.

Comment: @user735415: If it's true that you are 12 years old, I am afraid that this may not be the site for you. There is, unfortunately, an age limit due to US Law. <http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61770/must-be-above-13-to-use-stack-exchange-sites> Another reason that this site may not be for you is that you are not being particularly polite to people who are trying to help you. This site is also not here to "supply code", but to help you work through problems that you are facing in programming.

Comment: @Black Frog: Its alright man. I think he has got what he is looking for. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really should be reading a good book on coding and doing some tutorials to get an idea of how to do this, but the concept of a flag is simple.

In the class where your man is moved have a bool called `bCanMove` or similar, and set that to `false` when the class is initialised.

Once your "ready, steady, go" sequence finishes you set that to `true`.

The next step is check this flag in the code where you perform your movement, obviously I can't see your code but I expect you've got a method with a name similar to `didAccelerate` — in there just check to see if the boolean is true or not, and don't do anything if it isn't, for example:

```
if(!bCanMove)
{
    return;
}
```

As I can't see your code I don't know whether you're relying on inbuilt mechanisms etc., but as other people have stated (and myself) you shouldn't really be asking these kinds of questions on here — not because you're new to coding but more the way you've phrased the question, nobody can really help without any details and it's something you would't need to ask if you did a little more reading ;)

At a bare minimum you should read this: http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/ but that's not going to help you if you don't understand some basic programming concepts (and it would appear you don't) — for that there is no substitute for a good book/tutorial.

Comment: +1 for trying to help, even though personally I wish this "question" had been left unanswered.

Comment: and for addressing the real issue, rather than just slapping down some code.

Comment: Thanks Josh, I knew the type of response this question would usually get and figured it was better to try suggest how to fix the real problem as opposed to the code problem!

Comment: how can i create a bool property, this didnt help me by the way